# Does manage.py change its PID?

Tags: python, django, exec

I am trying to spawn a django process that lives on after the calling script died. But I need it's PID.

So I wrote the following code:

```
def runserver():
  print("START PID: " + str(os.getpid()))
  pid = os.fork()

  if pid == 0:
      #cmd = "/usr/bin/env python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:2869"
      print("IN THE CHILD PID: " + str(os.getpid()))
      os.execvp("python", ["", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:2869"])
  else:
      print("PARENT PID: " + str(os.getpid()))
      print("CHILD PID: " + str(pid))
      updatepid("runserver", pid)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
START PID: 13019
PARENT PID: 13019
CHILD PID: 13020
IN THE CHILD PID: 13020
```

But now when I check the live processes:

```
> ps aux | grep python | grep -v grep
sandro   13031  0.4  0.3 296080 23756 pts/2    Sl   22:14   0:01 /home/sandro/.virtualenvs/polling/bin/python2.7 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:2869
```

The pid changed! What on earth is going on???

Comment: I *know* I'm going to regret asking this, but *why* are you starting runserver from your script?

Comment: Mostly an experiment for myself. Just putting together a quick hacky script that keeps track of all of the processes for my pet django site. No worries, not part of prod or anything ;) When I'm done inventing the wheel, is there a tool that already does stuff like this that you can suggest?

Comment: There isn't really anything I can suggest, since I always run Django under mod_wsgi. And there are lots of httpd management tools out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see the other PID then there is definitely a new process.  You can easily find the place where the new process spawned.  Start in [`django.core.management.commands.runserver`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py?rev=17678#L41) and you'll come to [`django.utils.autoreload.python_reloader`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/autoreload.py#L109).  When `python_reloader` called first time in a process it goes to `restart_with_reloader` where you can see this:

```
exit_code = os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, sys.executable, args, new_environ)
```

Thereby, with your script you get two processes: one where `runserver` is executing and one (spawned) with webserver.  Check it:

```
START PID: 3091
PARENT PID: 3091
CHILD PID: 3092
IN THE CHILD PID: 3092

$ ps ax | grep runserver | grep -v grep
3092 pts/1    S      0:00  runserver 0.0.0.0:2869
3093 pts/1    Sl     0:05 /home/kirill/testenv/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:2869
```

Comment: @Sandro: If you passed on the name of the process in the execvp call in the first place, you would have immediately made out that there always were two processes. `os.execvp("python", ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:2869"])`. Its always a good practice to do this

Comment: @Kirill You nailed it. I have no idea why I didn't just grep the code base for spawn! Thank you!

Comment: @Phani I'm not sure I follow. What does adding the first argument do?

Comment: os.execvp's takes the name of the program as the first element of the second argument. You should pass the name explicitly like this whenever you call os.execvp. If you did so in your script, your grep "python" would have yielded two results, one for each process, thus reducing the confusion.